# Jetty doesn't start from WTP plugin

Tags: jetty, eclipse-wtp

When I start Jetty server in Eclipse (using the jetty-wtp plugin) the console output this error message：
`Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/transaction/UserTransaction`

My installed environment is:

1. JDK        1.6.0
2. jetty      8.0.0.M2
3. [jetty-wtp](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/updates/jetty-wtp/development)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the JTA API to your classpath. You can download from the java.net Maven repo at

```
http://download.java.net/maven/2/javax/transaction/jta/
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. by the way i find this site http://www.docjar.com/ to download jar package.

Comment: uhhh. how do i add the JTA JAR to the CP so it will be found when eclipse starts jetty?

Answer (score 2):

> > > "uhhh. how do i add the JTA JAR to the CP"

Go to the "Server" view (I use the bottom left list popup list), then double-click on the Jetty Server at localhost. This will bring up the configuration. Select "open launch configuration" underlined link. This brings up a configuration panel, then add to the classpath the missing jar: javax.transaction_1.1.1. This jar is located in the jetty/lib dir. I was looking for it on Oracle website, but there, the link is broken.